# Convergence in probability

Tags: statistics

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ converge in probability to a constant $c$, then does $1-X_1, 1-X_2, \ldots$ converge in probability to $1-c$? Is there a way to show this is true / is there an already existent theorem for this?

Comment: This should be obvious from the definition.  If $X_i$ is within $\epsilon$ of $c$, then $1-X_i$ will be within $\epsilon$ of $1-c$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X_n$ converges in probability to a constant $c$, then this means that

$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+_0 : \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n-c|>\epsilon) = 0 \; .$$

If you rewrite:

$$|X_n - c| = |c-X_n| = |c-1+1-X_n| = |(1-X_n)-(1-c)| \; ,$$

then you see that $1-X_n$ also converges in probability to $1-c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is any continuous function, and $X_n \to X$ in probability, then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in probability.  This is sometimes called the [continuous mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability).